# How to get logs and write them to a file with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, logging

I'm using Node.js, and I want to make a function that gets all **console logs** (that use `console.log(message)`).
How would I get all console logs and write them to a file (not *overwrite*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach would be to override the `log` function on the console with your function that logs the data and also writes to the file system.

Here's the general idea:

```
function attachFSLogger(filePath) {
  // remember the old log method
  const oldLog = console.log; // remove this line if you only want to log into the file

  // override console.log
  console.log = (...messages) => {

    // log the console message immediately as usual
    oldLog.apply(console, messages); // remove this line if you only want to log into the file

    // asynchronously append to the file log
    fs.appendFile(filePath, messages.join('\n'), (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  }
}

attachFSLogger('./logs.txt');

console.log('test'); // logs 'test' and also appends 'test' to logs.txt
```

If you expect to log things frequently, using a stream would be more [efficient](https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-object-streams/):

```
function attachFSLogger(filePath) {
  // remember the old log method
  const oldLog = console.log; // remove this line if you only want to log into the file

  // create a write stream for the given file path
  const fsLog = fs.createWriteStream(filePath, {
    flags: 'a' // 'a' means appending
  })

  // override console.log
  console.log = (...messages) => {

    // log the console message immediately as usual
    oldLog.apply(console, messages); // remove this line if you only want to log into the file

    // stream message to the file log
    fsLog.write(messages.join('\n'));
  }
}

attachFSLogger('./logs.txt');

console.log('test'); // logs 'test' and also appends 'test' to logs.txt
```

With that being said, there are many libraries out there that do things like this for you and have already been thoroughly tested.

Here's a couple:

- [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)
- [bunyan](https://github.com/trentm/node-bunyan)

Comment: `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\logs.txt'
    at Error (native)` That's what it returned when I tried it

Comment: It's a permissions problem. Run the script as an administrator or in a non-restricted folder.

Comment: Thanks! But it doesn't write to a new line... How do I make a newline each time it logs?

Comment: Just prepend a `'\n'` to the messages. As in `fsLog.write('\n' + messages.join('\n'))`

Answer (score 0):

For nodejs libraries, [npm repo](https://www.npmjs.com/) is your friend - you can find lots of them and try what's best suited for your needs. e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/log first result on searching `log`.

You could of course also implement your own hook into console to do it as well, by overwriting the console functions with your own functions that write to a file of your choice, e.g:

```
var fs = require('fs');

function myLog(file) {
  return function() {
    fs.appendFileSync(file || 'log.txt', arguments.join('\n'));
  }
}

console.log = myLog();
console.warn = myLog();
console.error = myLog('errorLog.txt');
```

Comment: so instead of `console.log()` I would use `myLog()`? Also, is `console.log` the logs, or am I just overwriting the function?

Comment: I just tried using that code and I got an Error: `    fs.appendFileSync(file | 'log.txt', arguments.join('\n');
                                                           ^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list` **The arrow is pointing to the closing bracket of the `arguments.join` function**

Comment: missed a closing bracket there - it was just a general direction though... updated now

Comment: And now I got another error: `TypeError: arguments.join is not a function`
EDIT: Yeah, arguments has no join method

Comment: Ok so I made arguments an array to make it work with .join, then I tried using the code. But of course, another error: `return binding.writeBuffer(fd, buffer, offset, length, position);
                   ^

Error: EBADF: bad file descriptor, write` EDIT: Here's some code: `var fs = require('fs');
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
function myLog(file) {
  return function() {
    fs.appendFileSync(file | 'log.txt', args.join('\n'));
  }
}

console.log = myLog('consoleLog.txt');`

Comment: check the other update related to the `file | 'log.txt` which was wrong - actually meant to use `||`

Comment: yeah no it didn't work `return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^

Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\consoleLog.txt'`

Comment: Actually, I ran as admin and this happened: `[object Object]
function require(path) {
    try {
      exports.requireDepth += 1;
      return self.require(path);
    } finally {
      exports.requireDepth -= 1;
    }
  }
[object Object]
C:\Program Files\nodejs\(file),js
C:\Program Files\nodejs`

Comment: maybe use an absolute file like `D:/temp/log.txt` or relative to where your app is running e.g. `__dirname + '/log.txt'` to avoid permission issues

Answer (score 0):

**logger.js**

```
var fs = require('fs'); 
var log = [];

//override default console.log behaviour
console.log = function(d) {
    process.stdout.write(d + '\n');
    log.push(d); //intercept every log and keep the value
};

//log to file 
function log(filePath, clb){
  clb = clb || function(){}; //optional callback
  fs.truncate(filePath, 0, function() {
    fs.writeFile(filePath, string, function (err) {
      clb(err)
    });
  });
}

module.exports = log;
```

then inside your code import the file and call the function when needed.

```
var logger = require('./logger');
logger.log('log.txt', function(err){
 if(err) 
   console.log(err);
 //else ok  
});
```

Comment: Returned: `Error: Cannot find module './logger'`

Comment: you have to put the first block of code inside a separate javascript file. i used logger.js as a name (the require is looking for that file). this is why you're getting the error.